# How to show desktop when remotely accessing Debian?

Tags: debian, gnome, remote-desktop, startx, xming

**Client**: *Win7* with *Xming* Server installed. Using *putty* to access with allowing *X11*.

**Remote**: Debian 3.2.73 with GNOME as the GUI environemt. And `X11Forward=yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

I can launch GUI tools like Gedit for example with no problems. But I need to see the whole Desktop not just tools that I type in the shell. I've tried typing `startx` but it gives errors and doesn't work.

How can I display the whole desktop on my local machine?

**Error Message** 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X11 forwarding is only forwarding *windows* that are spawned within your current session.  Since your desktop isn't a window it can't be forwarded in this manner.  You'll need to use something like VNC to get remote access to your desktop.

Comment: Actually it is possible to forward an X11 desktop, using XDMCP, but it's rather complicated compared to VNC. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/xdmcp for details (including Xming setup).

Comment: I think that this is technically incorrect https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_window